# Can we hide or empty the response data coming from ajax call after ajaxcomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Can we hide or empty the response data coming from ajax call after 
   ajaxcomplete in angularjs?

Comment: Huhhh?  Please explain much more specifically what you are trying to do?  And, perhaps show us some relevant code.

Comment: For security purpose, I want to hide the json data that shows in firebug console after ajaxcomplete.

Comment: What data is it that you're trying to hide?  You can't prevent debugging tools from seeing the results of an ajax call - you simply can't.  You'd have to prevent the server from sending the data in the first place or prevent the client from requesting it.

Comment: I have already done a lot of work, and the situation is I can't go back and erase the whole code. I am asking, Is there anyway to hide these json data from hackers.

Comment: Nope, if the browser uses this data then it has access to them and so do debugging tools and hackers. If the data is sensitive they shouldn't be sent out. If you describe your problem in more detail: what are you trying to achieve? what is the purpose of that webpage? etc you might be able to get possible solutions...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide Ajax data responses from debugging tools or hackers who have access to that same computer.  Conceptually, it just can't be done.  One can even use network sniffers to just watch the network data being transferred to/from your own computer so even outside of the browser, the data can be seen.

The browser is an inherently insecure environment.  Anything sent to the browser can be seen by any developer or hacker who has access to the receiving computer.

If you somehow think you require such browser-side security, then you probably need to rethink your design or rethink what is being sent to the client and process some data only on the server so it isn't sent to the insecure client environment.

Comment: I am fetching the only data which are nececssary to be rendered on screen, but these datas are in json format, anyone can parse and get all these data and make their own website, which I don't want.

Comment: @rohitjaiswal - Then you should probably secure your APIs to require a user account login and to not support cross origin access or only support cross origin access from your specific web domain.  If you don't support cross origin access, then a pure browser application from another domain won't be able to access your APIs - the browser will block them.  That doesn't prevent a proxy server from access your APIs (there is pretty much no way to block that).